# Why does this recursion give following output?

Tags: python, recursion

I have an exercise with following code:

```
def rec_count(number):
    print(number)
    # Base case
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    rec_count(number - 1)  # A recursive call with a different argument
    print(number)


rec_count(5)
```

which gives this output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I don't understand why after reaching 0 function doesn't go on with negative numbers, and gives numbers from 1 to 5 instead. Can someone explain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you expect it to go on into negative numbers? It clearly returns when it hits ``number == 0``.

Comment: Maybe running it in [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) makes it clearer to you. I suggest also adding indicators to the print calls like `print("down:", number)` and `print("up:", number)` to distinguish between the two print calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding negative numbers: when `rec_count(0)` is called, we encounter a `return` statement before reaching `rec_count(0-1)`.  As soon as a return statement is reached, execution of the function ends, so `rec_count(-1)` is never called.

Regarding increasing numbers: note that there is a `print(number)` statement *after* the recursive `rec_count` call.

Comment: Why then later on there are numbers from 1 to 5 as an output?

Comment: That's what I address with my second paragraph. Try tracing through what happens for the calls `rec_count(1)` and `rec_count(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the second print statement you have after the recursive call. When rec_count is called, the first print statement is hit and the expected print outs happen (5,4,3,2,1). The base case is also hit as expected. However, that is when the cascaded returns happen, and then the second print statement is hit in reverse order, resulting in the extra print outs you see.

Answer (score -1):

once you use return statement will end a function
it is continuing the count from 0 to 5 because you called that function and it didnt end

a Good solution would be to do something like the following

```
def rec_count(number):
   print(number)
   for i in range(number*2):
        number = number - 1
        print(number)
rec_count(5)
```